# VS2010 & SourceSafe 2005 - Logging into SourceSafe from the command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I have a custom application which brings together several resources and builds a Visual Studio project into an exe file I can then use to upgrade my company's website and database. This custom app uses System.Diagnostics.Process in a couple of places to access SourceSafe, I use the command SS ... -Y, to log into SourceSafe and process some events which works as I would expect. I'm not logged into the company's domain which is why I am manually logging into SourceSafe.

Now when I get to the part where I start building my VS2010 project, I'm using this command `devenv /Build Release /Out ..\Log.txt /project <MyProject>` it does not build my project, and the log file shows this error...

`The following files were specified on the command line: <Path to my VS project> These files could not be found and will not be loaded.`

The path to my project is correct and if I run it from a command window it loads the project, asks for my SourceSafe credentials and it builds. So my question is... Is there any way I can log into SourceSafe using the command line above, or by adding to the ProcessInfo parameters before I execute the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You may check out the thread below and see if it helps:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssourcecontrol/thread/8d00f574-7d9d-4a0d-aa0a-4c7832df0379

Comment: Thanks, not quite what I was looking for though, I do use those techniques already for other parts of the project. I need someway to log into Source Safe by passing in a username & password when I execute the (VS2010) denenv.exe process from my utility project, as you normally would do running a solution connected to SourceSafe in VS. Does anyone know if setting the environment variables SSUSER & SSPWD would help in this case?